# React - JSX - how to keep regext /r/n that come from API?

Tags: reactjs

I am need to render such strings that come from API.
They arrive to the component in a similar form:

```
console.log(companyName) // Company Name/r/n/Address 123/r/n/1234 City/r/n/ Country
```

However when I use that variable in the component the regex is removed and all is displayed in one line:

```
`<div>{companyName}</div>` renders in one line as `Company Name Address 123 1234 City Country`
```

How can I keep the "next line" regex instructions so that the text will be displayed as:

```
Company Name
Address 123 
1234 City Country
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can convert companyName variable and render it like this:

```
companyName.replaceAll("/r", "").split("/n").map(item => <div key={item}>{item}</div)
```

Comment: `{companyName.replaceAll("/r", "").split("/n").map(item => <div key={item}>{item}</div>)} still showing in one line. In Devtools -> Elements also there are no HTML characters such as `<br >`
`

Comment: i try to my code on devtool and it still works:
`Company Name/r/n/Address 123/r/n/1234 City/r/n/ Country
`.replaceAll("/r", "").split("/n").map(item => console.log(item))